# SQL Remove duplicate records with MAX

Tags: sql, duplicates, max

My query returns some duplicate records.  I've figured out the reason is some assets have 2 records in the PS_ASSET_ACQ_DET table.  This is due to the way assets are set up by a certain group of users.

In the PS_ASSET_ACQ_DET table, there is a field called "seq_nbr_6" that gets incremented with each new record.  I would like to select record with the greatest value in this table for each asset.

I tried using MAx (seq_nbr_6) in the SELECT statement and then using a GROUP BY on all of the other fields in the SELECT statement but that didn't work for me.

I'm looking for a way to only return 1 record from the PS_ASSET_ACQ_DET table.  Thanks for your help and taking the time to look at this question....

```
SELECT 
pdr.ACCOUNT_FA AS acct,
ir.ERAC_BRANCH_LGCY_CD AS gpbr,
pdr.DEPTID,
pa.ASSET_ID,
pa.serial_id,
pa.tag_number,
pa.asset_type,
pa.DESCR,
pb.IN_SERVICE_DT,
pb.LIFE,
pdr.COST,
pant.ACCUM_DEPR AS accum_depr,
pant.NET_BK_VALUE AS net_book_value,
pdr.FISCAL_YEAR AS fy,
pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD AS ap,
pdr.category,
pad.voucher_id,
pad.po_id,
pdr.location AS loc1,
pant.location AS loc2

FROM PSFS.PS_ASSET pa

INNER JOIN PSFS.PS_BOOK pb ON pb.ASSET_ID= pa.ASSET_ID AND pb.BUSINESS_UNIT = pa.BUSINESS_UNIT 

INNER JOIN PSFS.PS_DEPR_RPT pdr ON pdr.ASSET_ID= pb.ASSET_ID AND pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT = pb.BUSINESS_UNIT AND pdr.BOOK = pb.BOOK

INNER JOIN PSFS.PS_ASSET_ACQ_DET pad ON pad.ASSET_ID= pb.ASSET_ID AND pad.BUSINESS_UNIT = pb.BUSINESS_UNIT AND pdr.BOOK = pb.BOOK

INNER JOIN PSFS.PS_ASSET_NBV_TBL pant ON pant.BUSINESS_UNIT = pb.BUSINESS_UNIT
AND pant.ASSET_ID = pb.ASSET_ID
AND pant.BOOK = pb.BOOK

INNER JOIN INTGRT_RPT.DIM_LOCATION IR ON pdr.deptid = ir.erac_branch_ps_org_cd AND ir.curr_lrd_row_flg = 1

WHERE pdr.ACCOUNT_FA IN ('130','150','315',330','350')
AND pdr.FISCAL_YEAR =2016
AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD =3
AND pdr.GROUP_ASSET_FLAG <> 'M'
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing your join on psfs.ps_asset_acq_det to:

```
INNER JOIN(   SELECT MAX(seq_nbr_6), voucher_id, po_id, asset_id
              FROM psfs.ps_asset_acq_det
              WHERE business_unit = p
              GROUP BY voucher_id, po_id, asset_id
          ) pad ON pad.ASSET_ID= pb.ASSET_ID
```